# bootstrap table in mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created the Desktop view for my website. However, I need to modify the `bootstrap` table for my mobile view. I need to merge two rows into one and make it a single row.

[image]

HTML CODE FOR DESKTOP VIEW:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>

        <tr align="center">
            <td>1 Part</td>
            <td>2 Parts</td>
            <td>Additional Parts</td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
            <td>$10.00</td>
            <td>$20.00</td>
            <td>$30.00</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: use divs instead of a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using flexbox (no library)

```css
[flex-row] {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

[flex-col] {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  [flex-row] {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  [flex-col] {
    flex: 1 0 95%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div flex-row>
  <div flex-col>
    <div>1 Part</div>
    <div>$10.00</div>
  </div>
  <div flex-col>
    <div>2 Parts</div>
    <div>$10.00</div>
  </div>
  <div flex-col>
    <div>Additional Parts</div>
    <div>$30.00</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using Bootstrap:

```css
.my-display [class^="col-"] {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row my-display">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="text-center">1 Part</div>
      <div class="text-center">$10.00</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="text-center">2 Parts</div>
      <div class="text-center">$10.00</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="text-center">Additional Parts</div>
      <div class="text-center">$30.00</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i need to change my table to div?

Comment: Yes. Using `<table>`s for layout stopped being acceptable in web design about 20 years ago. Unless you're displaying tabular data (think pagination, sorting, filtering, etc... ) don't use `<table>`s.

Answer (score 0):

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/9TgOciPlSKq4Krgi9qkB?p=preview)

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    1 part
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    10
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    2 parts
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    20
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    Additional parts
                </div>
         </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    30
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```